# Using a button click event, destroy the ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

Using plain old javascript version of ag-grid.

I would like to destroy the ag-grid that is in a div from a button click event.

How do i destroy the grid?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a method named `destroy()`.

**[As per documentation:](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/)**

> `destroy()`
> Gets the grid to destroy and release resources. If you are using Angular (version 1 or 2) you do not need to call this, as the grid links in with the AngularJS 1.x lifecycle. However if you are using Web Components or native Javascript, you do need to call this, to avoid a memory leak in your application.

Have a look at the **[Plunk - Destroy grid](https://plnkr.co/edit/hZcbAxNi8EN0L2G4v1wo?p=preview)** I created.

```
gridOptions.api.destroy();
```

As you can see, by calling this function, the grid gets destroyed.
As described in the documentation, it not only clears the DOM, but also takes care of memory leaks.

Comment: I need to destroy multiple grids on my page, I have created different instances on a vanilla JS page, how can I acces the ´gridOptios.api´ of each of those instances to destroy them?

Comment: Could you post it as a new question with code sample? It is difficult to understand the challenge and get the context from your comment.